# Swift hitTest:point withEvent to detect subview

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiview, xcode12

I'm trying to detect when subView is tap using `hitTest`. Here is my implementation:

```
class MyViews:UIView {
    override init (frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        
        for subview in self.subviews.reversed() {
            let subPoint = subview.convert(point, from:self);
            
            if let result = subview.hitTest(subPoint, with:event) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm adding the subViews:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doSomethingHere(_:)))
        
        let blueView = MyViews(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 38.0, y: 231.0), size: CGSize(width: 335.0, height: 444.0)))
        blueView.tag = 100
        blueView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
        blueView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        view.addSubview(blueView)
        
        let grey = MyViews(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 38.0, y: 20.0 ), size: CGSize(width: 279, height: 203.0)))
        grey.tag = 200
        grey.backgroundColor = .gray
        grey.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        grey.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        blueView.addSubview(grey)
        
        let white = MyViews(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 56.0 , y: 17.0 ), size: CGSize(width: 182.0, height: 92)))
        white.tag = 300
        white.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        white.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        grey.addSubview(white)
        
        let result = blueView.hitTest(CGPoint(x: 157.5, y: 149.0), with: nil)
        print(result ?? "no result")

    }
```

I'm simulating a touch on this line `let result = blueView.hitTest(CGPoint(x: 157.5, y: 149.0), with: nil)`

But the response from this function:

```
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        
        for subview in self.subviews.reversed() {
            let subPoint = subview.convert(point, from:self);
            
            if let result = subview.hitTest(subPoint, with:event) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
```

It always is nil. I don't understand why it should be returning the white view.

Any of you knows why this function is not returning the correct view?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you hitTest is never checking to see if the point is in the view.  Give this a whirl:

```
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    // if there are subviews, step through them
    // if the subview contains the point, call hitTest on the subview to see if the subview's subviews contain the point
    // if they do, return the result,
    // if they don't, return the subview that does contain the point.
    for subview in self.subviews.reversed() {
        let subPoint = subview.convert(point, from:self)
        if subview.point(inside: subPoint, with: event) == true {
            if let result = subview.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) {
                return result
            } else {
                return subview
            }
        }
    }
    // none of the subviews contain the point,(or there are no subviews) does the current view contain the point?
    // if yes, return self. otherwise, return nil
    if self.point(inside: point, with: event) == true {
        return self
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. I really appreciated

Comment: I appreciated too, you saved me!